# Date is string between hyphens in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have date formats that are as follows:

```
Date_str
19-12-2007
31-7-2009
3-1-2010
31-11-2009
etc.
```

I can't do the following:

```
CONCAT(RIGHT(Date_str,4),SUBSTRING(Date_str,3,3),LEFT(2))
```

because as you can see above, the dates are not the same length. Is there a way in SQL Server to extract the date as datetime/date?

I also tried

```
Convert(datetime, Date_str)
```

but it just threw an error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

Comment: store them as 'YYYY-MM-DD' and avoid this in all flavors of SQL :)

Comment: Date types have no format. Just *don't* store dates as strings

Comment: @scsimon on the contrary, use the proper date type and avoid any problems. Store as string, and you'll never be able to fix all the bugs. Try adding one day to that string for example. Or retrieving the month *name*

Comment: @PRIME the problem is that you used the wrong type to store dates. The only realistic solution is to use the correct type, `date`. You'll have to convert the localized data just once, but after that you won't have to worry about conversions and formats

Comment: Well, I didn't, someone else stored it like that and I have to work with it..

Comment: You'll have to fix it or you'll always run into such problems. For example, what happens when you have to perform date arithmetic? If you have to parse the string all the time, you won't be able to use any indexes on the column either

Comment: BTW you can't sort the current format, nor perform range searches, eg for entries in the last week. `31-7-2009` will always be considered later than `3-1-2010` due to lexigocraphical sorting

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the comment was based off the relative assumption that changing the current datatype isn't able to be done, especially since for it to be done, the data would have to be cleansed with a conversion.

Comment: @PRIME You can create a persisted computed column to create a real `date` field that you can index and use for sorting and querying

Comment: @scsimon that's just covering up the problem, not a solution that can be applied to all databases. Besides, it only covers up a small part of the problem. Perfomance will remain bad

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos and if the developer isn't an admin and thus can't alter the table? Or if (heaven forbid) this was developed by a third party? My point is of course date's shouldn't be stored as strings, but assumptions about environments also shouldn't be made

Comment: @scsimon then he shouldn't be changing field formats at all, since that would break existing applications. *Especially* third-party applications

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If 2012+, I would use Try_Convert().  This will return bogus dates as NULL.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Date_str] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values
 ('19-12-2007')
,('31-7-2009')
,('3-1-2010')
,('31-11-2009')

Select *
      ,try_convert(date,Date_Str,105) 
 from @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
Date_str    (No column name)
19-12-2007  2007-12-19
31-7-2009   2009-07-31
3-1-2010    2010-01-03
31-11-2009  NULL             -- Notice 11/31 is NOT a date
```

Comment: Not bad John Cappalletti! I just used it in a SELECT statement:
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetime, Date_str,105) FROM TABLE

Comment: @PRIME Try_Convert can make things easier.  As you well know, when dates are stored as stings ...  a whole bunch can go wrong.  :)

Answer (score 1):

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql for date formats

You probably need

```
CONVERT(DateTime, Date_str, 105)
```

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, the only realistic solution is to convert that string into a proper `date`-typed column. The current format doesn't allow date sorting, or search for a range of dates, eg to find entries in the last week, or between one date and the other.

Parsing with `CONVERT` or `TRY_PARSE` means that no indexes can be used to speed up queries. Each time :

```
WHERE CONVERT(Date, Date_str, 105) > '20170101'
```

is used, the server will have to scan the entire table to convert the data, *then* filter the rows.

If you can't change the type of the field itself, you can create a persisted computed column that returns the value as a date and add indexes to it. You'll be able to use that column for indexed querying:

```
alter table SomeTable add date2 as TRY_convert(Actual_Date,date_str,105) PERSISTED

create index IX_SomeTable_ActualDate on SomeTable (Actual_Date)
```

This will allow you to perform sorting without tricks:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SomeTable
ORDER BY Actual_Date
```

Or run range queries that take advantage of the IX_SomeTable_ActualDate index:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SomeTable
Where Actual_Date Between DATEADD(d,-7,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

If you have 1000 rows, you could get 1000 times better performance.

Existing applications won't even notice the change. Newer queries and applications will be able to take advantage of indexing and sorting

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: my column (<my_date_field>) had date values in the form of

```
2021-01
2021-02
2021-10
2021-12
```

and so on, **with data type of nvarchar(4000)**, and I always ran into the `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.` error (when trying e.g. `CAST(<my_date_field> AS DATE)` or `CAST(CAST(<my_date_field> AS VARCHAR(7)) AS DATE)` etc.)

I was able to convert them to date with the following code:

```
SELECT
CONVERT(date, <my_date_field> + '-01') AS first_day_of_month
FROM my_table
```

which resulted in

```
2021-08-01
2021-07-01
2021-06-01
2021-05-01
```